# Is there a way for a Facebook user to find the Ad Account ID of their own Ad Account without API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

Given an Ad User, it is simple enough to request from the Facebook Ads API a list of Ad Account ID's with which that User is associated. The use case I am wondering about is if a User is associated with multiple Ad Accounts (is that allowed?) and has not named each Ad Account. It seems to me that some app trying to manage this User's ads for them cannot know which of this User's Ad Accounts to use because they are not named and the ID's are just numbers. So my thought is that the User could tell the app explicitly which Ad Account to use but the User could only do this for nameless Ad Accounts if they knew their Ad Account ID. Any advice or things I'm missing that could be helpful to me?

Comment: I'm not sure this is a technical problem but more of a problem you will have to solve with UI.

Comment: Ooh, I see what you're saying. So basically let the user distinguish between the accounts FOR us by showing them other info they might recognize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Facebook Ads User can see their Ad Account ID's on the Power Editor (https://www.facebook.com/ads/manage/powereditor/) which currently you need to use in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

To improve UI in this case, I would show as many details as you can extract from an ad account configuration and present them to the user.

Name of the account is just a label that user sets, can you rely on it if user names several accounts in same way? If it's missing it doesn't mean you cannot use other parameters to describe the account. You can show account id, balance, business address, currency, etc...

Answer (score 0):

By far the easiest way I've noticed is to go to this link:

https://www.facebook.com/ads/manager/accounts/